# Querying an SQL table to get all new values in a column according to filter in another column

Tags: sql

Sorry I couldn't make the question clearer, let me explain it here.

I have a table that has two columns:

```
year, ID

------------

2013, 01

2013, 27

2013, 33

2014, 22

2014, 33

2014, 01

2014, 13

2015, 45

2015, 13

2015, 22
```

What I want to do is the following: check all new IDs that appeared in 2014 from 2013, and all new IDs that appeared in 2015 from 2014, and so on and so forth...

So, from the example above, the expected answer to my query should be a table like:

```
year, new
-------------

2014, 2

2015, 1
```

Since in 2014 there are two new IDs in relation to 2013 (22 and 13), and in 2015 there is one new ID in relation to 2014 (45).

Sorry for the horrible formatting, I'm new to this site. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you explain in detail what do you mean by **new value**. How do you define it?

Comment: what is the database?

Comment: @ArnoldParge Sure! A new value is simply a value that appeared in the year X but wasn't there in the year X-1 (which is the case for the values 22 and 13 for the year 2014 in my example).

Comment: @sam hey, I'm new to sql, so not sure what you mean by your question. I built the database myself using pythong and the sqlite3 library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `lag()`:

```
select year, count(*)
from (select t.*, lag(year) over (partition by id order by year) as prev_year
      from t
     ) t
where prev_year is null or prev_year < year - 1
group by year;
```

Comment: Hey friend! It worked! Sorry, I forgot to add one thing that you wrote and initially thought it didn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the all codes that didn't exist with a year  y - 1 that shower at year y:

```
 with cte as
 (
select cast(2013 as int) as year, '01' as id

union select 2013, 27

union select 2013, 33

union select 2014, 22

union select 2014, 33

union select 2014, '01'

union select 2014, 13

union select 2015, 45

union select 2015, 13

union select 2015, 22
)
select year, count(*) from cte a where not exists(select 1 from cte b where a.year -1 = b.year and a.id = b.id)
and a.year -1 in (select distinct year from cte)
group by year
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I chose to go with Gordon's solution because the actual table is huge with many entries, and it would not be practical to union select everything.